# react native KeyboardAvoidingView moves top input off the screen

Tags: react-native, keyboard, scrollview, expo

I have a project with a few inputs and I've found a way for the bottom inputs to not be hidden by the keyboard anymore. However with this solution I've found that if I tap on the top inputs I get the same behavior and they are moved off the screen (and the user cannot see what he or she is typing anymore)

here is my code regarding the issue:

```
const keyboardVerticalOffset = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 10 : 10

<KeyboardAwareScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true} style={{            
            borderTopRightRadius: 20,
            borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
            backgroundColor: "#d1d1d1",
                    position: 'relative',
                    flex: 1
          }}
          contentStyle={{
          }}>
          <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='position' keyboardVerticalOffset={keyboardVerticalOffset}>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 28,
                color: "#404040",
                fontWeight: "700",
                marginLeft: 12,
                marginBottom: 10,
                marginTop: 20,
                textAlign: "center"
              }}
            >
              Enter your details below
            </Text>
            <Form>
              <Item stackedLabel rounded style={{borderColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0)', marginLeft: 5, marginRight:5}}>
                <View style={styles.textInputStyle}>
                <Input
                  placeholderTextColor="#9e9e9e"
                  placeholder="Address (Street, City)"
                  onChangeText={e => this.setState({ address: e })}
                  style={{ fontFamily: "nunito" }}
                />
                </View>
              </Item> //there are a lot more items but I don't want to paste them here and make this post larger than it should be
            </Form>
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

EDIT: I've found that also the bottom inputs aren't moved all the way up either, and they are instead aligned with the keyboard's top (where the keyboard ends and the screen of the project starts) so perhaps there is a hint somewhere in there for something larger

EDIT 2: Here is a copy of my app.json and package.json
app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "CCC",
    "slug": "ccc",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "33.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "android": {
      "package": "abc.abc.abc"
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": false
    },
    "description": ""
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.6",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "expo": "^33.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~5.0.1",
    "firebase": "^6.5.0",
    "formik": "^1.5.8",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.18.5",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.3.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.16.0",
    "react-native-smart-carousel": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "3.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0",
    "truffle": "^5.0.34",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3",
    "web3": "0.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Can you provide expo snack example and  type of OS?

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/HyuXSZ2tS it seems to work fine on the snack. which leads me to believe there isn't an issue with the code. Do you know what else it may be?

Comment: check version of expo and packages in snack and yours

Comment: ah yes, my expo version is lower, are there any dangers or precautions I should take before updating my expo project?

Comment: What is you version?

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of the issue?

Comment: my version is `^33.0.0` and I cannot upload photos yet

Comment: in which OS it's a problem ? or in both?

Comment: in my current expo OS (33) is the problem. the Snack's expo version (35) it runs fine. Should I take any precautions before updating my project?

Comment: Can  you provide: screen shot of the issue, app.json, package.json?

Comment: last one: can you attach screenshot of the problem?

Comment: please attach screenshot and try this snack code in your project: https://snack.expo.io/rkF7u7hFH

Comment: @Oleg my apologies for wasting your time, friend. It seems as though the reason behind `KeyboardAvoidingView` acting weird was because I was using Google Keyboard...once I switched to the default keyboard everything was working as expected